# what c# object is mapped to js dictionary?

Tags: c#, javascript, json

I want to send a json from c# application to the client.

I want it to be as

```
obj = { "key1": "value1",  "key2": "value2"}
```

What c# object should I use and serialze ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var json = new { key1 = value1, key2 = value2 };
return Json(json);
```

has worked for me.

Comment: and if I want to save this as a class memeber? How to over-cross the anonymus type?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/)

Json.NET is a popular high-performance JSON framework for .NET

Features

- Flexible JSON serializer for converting between .NET objects and JSON
- LINQ to JSON for manually reading and writing JSON
- High performance, faster than .NET's built-in JSON serializers
- Write indented, easy to read JSON
- Convert JSON to and from XML
- Supports .NET 2, .NET 3.5, .NET 4, Silverlight and Windows Phone

Comment: OK. We can use Json.Net. where is the answer to the question `What c# object should I use and serialze ?`

Answer (score 0):

I agree with using the Json() ActionResult if this is to be used within a controller.
If you want to serialize to JSON at another level, you can use the built in JavaScriptSerializer class

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx

JavaScriptSerializer takes any class instance or native type and serializes its public properties.  You can have it exclude public properties by putting

[ScriptIgnore]

above the property declaration.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.scriptignoreattribute.aspx